# How to move all contents of Directory (not including Parent) to another directory Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy script which takes a 2 zip files, unzips them, then processes them.

The problem I have is when I go to unzip the zip files, each unzipped file produces a subfolder then the content of the unzip file not the content itself.

*Example:*

**Currently this happens when I unzip**

`content-1232.zip -> /content-1232/content/<all content here>`

**What I want is**

`content-1232.zip -> /content-1232/<all_content>`

or

*Put  into a new directory*

`content-1232.zip -> /new_directory/<all_content>`

I tried this but to no avail:

```
Path basePath = Paths.get(output.getAbsolutePath())
Path srcPath = Paths.get(pdfContent.getAbsolutePath())
Path targetPath = basePath

Files.move(srcPath, targetPath.resolve(basePath.relativize(srcPath)))
```

Seems like a very simple thing to do but I'm not have any luck. How can I accomplish this in groovy? Any help will be appreciated

**Edit:**

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Beginning unpacking of content...")


    def output = new File("/Users/Haddad/Desktop/workspace/c")
    def pdfContent = new File("/Users/Haddad/Desktop/workspace/c/pdf-content")


    // Look for test1 and test2 production content zip file, ensure there's only 1 and unzip
    List appZip = FileUtil.discoverFiles(output, true, "test1-production-content-.*\\.zip")
    List compliZip = FileUtil.discoverFiles(output,true,"test2-production-content-.*\\.zip")

    assert appZip.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of test1 content zip, actual size is: " + appZip.size()
    assert compliZip.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of test2 content zip, actual size is " + appZip.size()

    def outputAppZip = new File(output.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+appZip.get(0).getName()+"-intermediate");
    def outputCompliZip = new File(output.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+compliZip.get(0).getName()+"-intermediate");

    ZipUtil.unzipToDisk(appZip.get(0), outputAppZip )
    ZipUtil.unzipToDisk(compliZip.get(0), outputCompliZip )


    // move it to pdf content
    List applicationContent = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(output, "one-production-content-.*-intermediate", true)
    assert applicationContent.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of test1 contents " + applicationContent.size()

    def success = FileUtil.copy(applicationContent.get(0), pdfContent)
    assert success, "Could not copy tt content"

    // move pdf content
    List complianceContent = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(output, "two-production-content-.*-intermediate", true)
    assert complianceContent.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of test2 contents " + complianceContent.size()
    success = FileUtil.copy(complianceContent.get(0), pdfContent)
    assert success, "Could not copy pdf content"

    // rename to not be unsupported
    List unsupportedDirs = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(pdfContent, "_unsupported_.*", true)
    for (File file : unsupportedDirs) {
        file.renameTo(new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName().replace("_unsupported_", "")))
    }


    logger.info("Completed!")
}
```

Comment: Show your unzip code.

Comment: Nothing to do with Java or grails. Tags removed

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar just added the code. I hope this doesn't add any unnecessary complexity to my question

Comment: @tim_yates I added the java tag again. Groovy and Java code are usually interchnagable so a solution in core java would work here as well

Comment: `grails` tag is completely misleading - removed again. There's not a bit of grails specific code in this problem.

Comment: What's the structure of each zip file? Is the directory `content` in them or are the files laid out flat (I'm guessing the former)? We shouldn't have to pull teeth to get information, your question is incomplete. Also specify what the `FileUtil` and `ZipUtil` classes are, because those are the ones doing the work.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you are correct, it's not flat. When I unzip `content-1232.zip` it produces  directory `content-1232` which contains <all_content>

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitSarkar however this is why I didn't want to post code. Generically speaking, based on the code you've seen and even without, how can I move the contents of a directory not including the Parents folder to another folder. This is a generic question which requires no context

Comment: @mosawi That's not how it works. We are not consultants that get paid for answering a random question you throw at us. We are programmers that like to solve problems. And in order to do that we need to understand the context first. If you want to work with vague information, ask your superiors.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

**Input**:

```
test.zip
--- test
------ test.txt
```

**Output**:

```
<someFolder>
--- test.txt
```

**Code**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main main = new Main();

        Path input = main.getInputPath(args);
        Path output = main.getOutputPath(args);

        main.extract(input, output);
        main.flatten(output);
    }

    private final Path getInputPath(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: Main <inputFile> [<outputDirectory>]");
        }

        Path input = Paths.get(args[0]);

        if (!isRegularFile(input)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not a file.", input.toFile().getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        return input;
    }

    private final Path getOutputPath(String[] args) throws IOException {
        return args.length < 2 ? Files.createTempDirectory(null) :
                Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(args[1]));
    }

    private final void extract(Path input, Path output) throws IOException {
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(input.toFile()))) {
            for (ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zis.getNextEntry()) {
                String fileName = ze.getName();

                if (fileName.contains("__MACOSX")) {
                    continue;
                }

                File file = new File(output.toFile(), fileName);

                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    Files.createDirectories(file.toPath());
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("Extracting: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    for (int len = zis.read(buffer); len > 0; len = zis.read(buffer)) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private final void flatten(Path output) throws IOException {
        List<Path> children = Files.list(output)
                .collect(toList());

        if (children.size() == 1) {
            Path path = children.get(0);
            Files.list(path)
                    .forEach(f -> {
                        try {
                            System.out.printf("Moving %s to %s.\n", f.toFile().getAbsolutePath(),
                                    output.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
                            Files.move(f, Paths.get(output.toFile().getAbsolutePath(), f.toFile().getName()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                        }
                    });

            Files.delete(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Random downvote, care to explain?

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitSarkar. Not sure who downvoted your answer or my question but this answer works great. I was wishing for a simple solution but this looks to work a lot better than what I had

Comment: On the flatten method you have on the first line `List<Path> children = Files.list(output).collect(toList());` where is toList() ?

Comment: I don't see `isRegularFile` method as well? Interested to see how it checks file type

Comment: [toList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)

[isRegularfile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-)

This is why IDEs exist. Ask it to do static imports.